# Area between vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

The vectors $\langle 2, 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1,0 \rangle$ form a triangle with the area $\dfrac{base \times height}{2}$. However normal vectors are supposed to tell what the area is too, but the normal vector that I just found through wolframalpha is $\langle 0,0,2\rangle$.

$\dfrac{base \times height}{2}$ equals $\dfrac{2 \times 1}{2} = 1$.

What step am I doing wrong here!?

Comment: Terminology note: a "normal vector" would be orthogonal to both your input vectors, but it could have any length. (You can check that $\langle 0,0,k \rangle$ is orthogonal to your inputs for any $k$.) What you're describing is the *cross product*, which is not only normal but also has a specific length.

Comment: You may look after the Gram-determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of the cross product is the area of the *parallelogram* with the vectors for sides.

You should multiply by $\frac12$ to get the area of the *triangle*.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Area is considered to be a vector quantity in physics whose direction is perpendicular to both sides of the triangle. The magnitude of area is calculated as the magnitude of the vector product or *cross product* of both vectors. If we consider the cross product we will get the magnitude as |A||B|sin(θ). But if we take in consideration the fact that |A| and |B|sin(θ) are in fact the magnitude of the base and height of the parallelogram formed by vector A and B then their 
product will be the area of the parallelogram. Since we know that the area of a triangle is half the area of a parallelogram thus we can simply use half of the cross product of the two vectors to find the area of the triangle formed by them.[The following image explains the direction of the area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS9ZB.png)